# Using the idiom "go through the roof"

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

"If the manager sees this type of work his anger will go through the roof" Is this sentence correct? Or is there a better way of phrasing it?

I found that "go through the roof" is an idiom, so wondering if it could be used like "If the manager sees this quality of work, he will go through the roof". Does that makes sense or communicate properly?
This is somewhat shorter.

The idea is to convey to someone that he has done poor-quality work, so make it of better quality quickly. Otherwise, if the manager sees this lower quality work he is gonna get very angry.

Comment: My dad went through the roof when I came home drunk aged 14. Totally normal expression.

Comment: Or you could say he 'hit the roof'.

Comment: In Glasgow they say 'he threw an epi' but I strongly advise you not to use that expression.

Comment: I would tend to say **he** hit or went through the roof, not "his anger".

Comment: We usually say [*He **hit** the roof*, not *He **went through** the roof*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+hit+the+roof%2Che+went+through+the+roof&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) And it's usually ***him*** who does thsat, not ***his anger***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - David Zweck was angry when he found out his wife was seeing another man. But he went through the roof when he discovered she betrayed him with the Catholic priest who had been counseling them on their marriage. _New York Post_ June 23 2022, He went through the roof when he was billed $1,247 for the changes. _New York Times_ 4 September 1975, He went through the roof when he heard his film described with a political twist, _Washington Post_ 13 June 1988 I went through the roof when I saw it, because it contains a purported quote from the committee's findings _Canadian senator_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I only said we *usually* use ***hit the roof***. Note that there were at least *some* hits for *he **went through** the roof* as linked to my previous comment. But if I search for ***Dad*** instead of ***he***, there aren't even enough instances of ***Dad went through the roof*** to show on the chart. I rest my case.

Comment: ...of course, in BrE (not AmE, I think) we can also say *he **went spare***

Answer (score 2):

***[go through the roof](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-through-the-roof)*** has two main meanings:

> to rise to a very high level:
>
> - Prices have gone through the roof.

informal
(also hit the roof)

> to get very angry:
>
> - When I was expelled from school, my parents went through the roof.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

> [This expression](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/through-the-roof#:%7E:text=This%20expression%20originated%20in%20the,shoot%20up%20quickly%2C%20or%20stocks.) originated in the first half of the 1900s. It probably is related to a literal roof of a house. If something actually were to go through the roof of a house, it would have risen very high and fast, and unexpectedly as well.

(writingexplained.org)

Comment: Didn't you just copy text from websites, which OP could have found on his or her own?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - this site is for English learners, is it ? Usage of idiomatic expressions is never simple, especially to NNS. The dictionary entry I suggest is clear and easy to understand I think. And that may help  the user. All comments above are interesting, but possibly unclear about usage to a learner.

Comment: I agree that those quotations might be helpful, but keep in mind [this site's guidelines](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/referencing): "Do *not* copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - ok bye.